# Multiple objects with the same name were found

Tags: ms-office, office365, office365-apps

I'm working on an App for Office that inserts text/images into specific parts of the current Word document, as far as I've investigated, the only way to achieve this is by using ContentControls and creating a binding with:

```
Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync();
```

Now, the problem is that when I have Content Controls inside both, the document body and the header/footer, I'm getting the following error:

**Code:** 3007

**Name:** Binding Creation Error

**Message:** Multiple objects with the same name were found.

According to [Microsoft's website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn595120.aspx)!, this is due to 2 or more CCs with the same name; but this is not the case since every CC that I created has an unique name, and when I move all of them to either the header/footer or the body, it works, the error just happens when they are located in different sections of the document.

This is the code I'm using:
    Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync("HeaderLogoCC","text",
    { id: 'logoBinding' }, function (result) 
    {
    if (result.status == "failed") 
    {
    result.error.message == "The named item does not exist."
    }

(I know my English is not the best, I apologize in advance for any mistake and I can try to make it more clear, if necessary).

Any help would be really appreciated,

Thanks!